# MagicalRecord is saving null when passed data inside a for loop

Tags: ios, core-data, for-loop, ios7, magicalrecord

I am using `AFNetworking` in order to call a web service all pull down data. The data gets put into the `responseobject` which I am then attempting to put into `CoreData`.

For some reason the data is not being stored into the `CoreData` entity. My code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] count]; i++) {

        NSString * topicID = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"];
        NSString * title = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSString * body = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"body"];
        NSString * category = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"];
        NSNumber * nFor = @([[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nFor"] intValue]);

        NSLog(@"Title being sent is %@",title);
        NSLog(@"Number of votes sent is %@",nFor);

        ExploreCD *exploreCD = [ExploreCD MR_createEntity];
        exploreCD.topicID = topicID;
        exploreCD.title = title;
        exploreCD.body = body;
        exploreCD.category = category;
        exploreCD.nFor = nFor;

        NSLog(@"Title being saved is %@",exploreCD.title);
        NSLog(@"Number of votes saved is %@",exploreCD.nFor);

        //[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    }
```

Here are what the `NSLogs` in my code are reading out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
2014-03-28 18:49:39.677 Karmo[8328:60b] Title being sent is a odio in
2014-03-28 18:49:39.677 Karmo[8328:60b] Number of votes sent is 0
2014-03-28 18:49:39.677 Karmo[8328:60b] Title being saved is (null)
2014-03-28 18:49:39.677 Karmo[8328:60b] Number of votes saved is (null)
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Title being sent is amet nunc viverra dapibus
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Number of votes sent is 0
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Title being saved is (null)
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Number of votes saved is (null)
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Title being sent is semper sapien a libero nam
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Number of votes sent is 2
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Title being saved is (null)
2014-03-28 18:49:39.678 Karmo[8328:60b] Number of votes saved is (null)
2014-03-28 18:49:39.679 Karmo[8328:60b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x109346550) NO CHANGES IN ** DEFAULT ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

I am saving these new CoreData Entities with this code after the for loop finishes in the success section of the `afnetworkwing` code.

```
    [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:nil completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        exploreCellData = [[ExploreCD MR_findAll] mutableCopy];

   }];
```

Comment: Do you have a solution? Any clue? It is really weird!

Comment: Nothing yet... I can't figure it out. I am wondering if the something is off with the initial MagicalRecord set-up. Because the other error that I am having is if I try and clear out the data by calling the `MR_truncateAll` method my app was crashing as well.

Comment: Where did your save this code?

Comment: @user2939977 yep, that could be a possibility: Do you have `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];` in your `application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your AppDelegate.m ?

Comment: "my app was crashing as well"  I think it would be helpful if you provide the crash report. And as already mentioned by @shingo.nakanishi, you need to save after importing.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana I am implementing the `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"CoreDataModel"];` in my `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in the AppDelegate.

Comment: @koen @shino.nakanishi I cam edited question to shoe the code I am currently using to save the records to `CoreData`. I do not have any crash report files yet for the app but will work on getting them for this problem if it will shelp solve it.

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi when I add in the `[ExploreCD Mr_truncateAll]` code this is the line of code that the breakpoint (highlighted green) takes me too in the app `results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` in the `+ (NSArray *) MR_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
`method of the `NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m` file.

Comment: `setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:` has the same effect. One question, your model is really named: **CoreDataModel** ?   (`CoreDataModel.xcdatamodeld`) ?

Comment: +1 because this is weird

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana Yes my model is really called CoreDataModel :)

Comment: Can you check if **exploreCD** is `nil`?         `NSLog(@"exploreCD is %@",exploreCD);` after         `ExploreCD *exploreCD = [ExploreCD MR_createEntity];`

Comment: You need to pass a context to saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock to make sure that your entities will be saved to a context.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana I never really figured it out... but I pulled out MagicalRecord and went back to using CoreData without it and everything seems to working

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. You only create the enities but your forgot to save them !

I think you can do something like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]; // New context
for (int i = 0; i < [[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] count]; i++) {
    NSString * topicID = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"];
    NSString * title = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString * body = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"body"];
    NSString * category = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"];
    NSNumber * nFor = @([[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nFor"] intValue]);

    NSLog(@"Title being sent is %@",title);
    NSLog(@"Number of votes sent is %@",nFor);

    ExploreCD *exploreCD = [ExploreCD MR_createEntityInContext:context];
    exploreCD.topicID = topicID;
    exploreCD.title = title;
    exploreCD.body = body;
    exploreCD.category = category;
    exploreCD.nFor = nFor;

    NSLog(@"Title being saved is %@",exploreCD.title);
    NSLog(@"Number of votes saved is %@",exploreCD.nFor);
}
// Save the datas
[context  MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (!success)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need save. like `saveWithBlock` etc.

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
 for (int i = 0; i < [[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] count]; i++) {

        NSString * topicID = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"];
        NSString * title = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSString * body = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"body"];
        NSString * category = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"];
        NSNumber * nFor = @([[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nFor"] intValue]);

        NSLog(@"Title being sent is %@",title);
        NSLog(@"Number of votes sent is %@",nFor);

        ExploreCD *exploreCD = [ExploreCD MR_createInContext:localContext];
        exploreCD.topicID = topicID;
        exploreCD.title = title;
        exploreCD.body = body;
        exploreCD.category = category;
        exploreCD.nFor = nFor;

        NSLog(@"Title being saved is %@",exploreCD.title);
        NSLog(@"Number of votes saved is %@",exploreCD.nFor);

        //[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I am still seeing the (null) values with your code above.

Comment: `save:` should be outside of the for loop. Can't go the `for loop` inside the `save: block`! That is for sure.

Comment: And the function to save is: `NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];`
`[localContext MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){ ... }];`

Comment: @user2939977 (*ﾟﾛﾟ)oh, I see. your problem `ExploreCD` property always `nil`, if you save or not.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana My English no good. I would like to check your mean. Did you mean `[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) { for(){ [ExploreCD MR_createInContext:localContext]; }` is NG.

Comment: And `NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]; for(){ [ExploreCD MR_createInContext:localContext]; } [localContext MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){ ... }];` is OK. ??